# golang is not parsing the last element of stdin

Tags: list, loops, go, stdin, listiterator

I am trying to write a golang program where it will parse the stdin line to line and compute the sum of all positive integers on each line.

Attached is the code:

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "os"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
)

func mytest(st string) bool {
    a, _ := strconv.Atoi(st)
    return a > 0

}
func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    for {
        line, err := reader.ReadString('\n')

        if err == io.EOF {
            //          fmt.Print(line)
            break
        }

        // fmt.Print(line)
        res := 0
        qq := strings.Split(line, " ")

        // fmt.Println(qq)

        for _, val := range qq {
            if mytest(val) {
                as, _ := strconv.Atoi(val)
                fmt.Println(as)
                res += as * as
            }

        }

        fmt.Println(res) // [test]

    }
}
```

I am not sure why the for loop cannot reach the last element of the list. 
For example, if the stdin is

```
3 -1 1 14
1 6 16
```

The output is:

```
10
37
```

so that 14 and 16 is not parsed in the inner for loop at

```
for _,val := range qq
```

Can anybody help me take a look?

Comment: Get rid of any trailing newlines: "\n" or "\r\n".

Comment: Hey Haw Wang,
update your code in `mytest` to 
`a,err := strconv.Atoi(st)
 if(err != nil){
  println(err.Error())
 }`
You should see the error.